# Can JSDoc's output be organized into "folders"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jsdoc, commonjs

I'm using [grunt-jsdoc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-jsdoc) to generate documentation from JSDoc comments, with the default templating.

In the generated docs, links to module documentation all show up in a single list under 'Modules'. This project uses React and Webpack, and will have a very large number of modules. A single list will quickly become impractical.

Is there some way to tell JSDoc to organize modules (or any other file, really) within a namespace, or a directory, or something -- purely as an organizational concern?

Ideally, the links to modules in the documentation index would mirror the file structure used in the project's source, but any step in this direction would be helpful.

I understand you can create your own templates for JSDoc, but that's more of a time sink than we cannot probably afford right now.